# How do you add co-ordinates in python?

Tags: python, graphics

So I'm trying to create a function that lets a user enter the length and width for a rectangle and for python to then draw that rectangle in the center of the graph (using the graphics module). So I was wondering how you can add co-ordinates as I am getting an error message. This is what I've got so far:

```
    def drawRectangle():
        win = GraphWin('Target',200,200)
        win.setCoords(0,0,200,200)
        width = int(input('Enter the width of your rectangle: '))
        length = int(input('Enter the length of your rectangle: '))
        **topLeft = Point(100,100)+Point(0,width/2)-Point(length/2,0)
        bottomRight = Point(100,100)-Point(0,width/2)+Point(length/2,0)**
        rec = Rectangle(Point(topLeft.getX, topLeft.getY), Point(bottomRight.getX, bottomRight.getY)) 
        rec.draw(win)
```

The bit thats messing up I've put in between two asterisks

help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where does the `Point` class come from? Is it your own class?

Comment: I thought that that is how you define co-ordinates? let me know if im wrong @will

Comment: I just looked at the graphics library, and noticed that it is a class there. It does not have the functionality built in to add points together.

Comment: right, thanks for letting me know. Can you see anyway around that?@will

Comment: @will The author(s) of `graphics` has been a bit strict, but in effects you cannot add two point, you add vectors.  On the other hand (I'm unable to verify as `graphics` is MS stuff, isn't it?) it is possible  that `Point` has methods to do what the OP needs to do.

Comment: the `graphics` i found was just a single file called `graphics.py`, but it's a pretty generic thing to search for. Looking at `dir(<instance of Point>)` i didn't see anything that suggested an easy way to add them...

Comment: @me It seems that `graphics` is generic (no MS stuff as I thought), and  looking at the doc it seems that all the objects support a set of methods that comprises clone() and move(dx,dy). So a Point can be `move`d and cannot be `add`ed to another one...

Answer (score 1):

Since `Point` is of another class, you'll have to write your own function to add a series of `Points` together.

You could try this, but i don't know if it would break anything (though i'd be surprised, since it seems that `+` isn't used for `Points`:

Add this in before you try to add any `Points`:

```
from graphics import *

p1 = Point(1,2)
p2 = Point(3,4)

def addPoints(self, other):
  return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

Point.__add__ = addPoints


for point in [p1, p2, p1+p2]:
    print "(%i, %i)" % (point.x, point.y)
```

Which gives:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(4, 6)
```

That might work, but i haven't tested it. If it does work, you could then redefine the other operations too.

Comment: I liked the refresher on adding behavior to a class (+1), and if I can tell something to the OP: "you should hurry to accept will's answer".  However, I am under the impression that the omission of an __add__ method should be regarded as a design choice.  But I'm open to change my mind...

Comment: [Here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py)'s the package. It doesn't mention anythin in there, it seems more that it's just quite simple package. IMO, it might also be handy to add a way to cast between arrays / tuples of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that x-coordinates are left to right and y-coords are top to bottom

```
centre   = Point(w_width/2,w_height/2)
topleft  = centre.clone().move(-r_width/2,-r_height/2)
botright = centre.clone().move(+r_width/2,+r_height/2)
```